# c++17 parallel algorithms and CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, parallel-processing, std, tbb

It looks like more and more standard libraries implementations are relying on TBB for their parallel algorithms. This is a bit surprising to me, as I didn't think that standard libraries would have external dependencies (outside of stuff like `pthread`), but that's a different question I imagine.

My issue is that I need to bake this into my `CMakeLists.txt` files now.

First bad news: There is no official CMake support for TBB, and TBB itself does not provide any `FindTBB.cmake` file. You can find it [here](https://github.com/CLIUtils/cmake/blob/master/FindTBB.cmake) [and](https://www.openmodelica.org/svn/OpenModelica/trunk/SimulationRuntime/cpp/CMake/FindTBB.cmake) [there](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/CMake/FindTBB.cmake) on the web, but if standard libraries start relying on it, it would be nice to have it officially supported by CMake. Is this coming further down the line?

Then, I need to have some slightly convoluted code in my `CMakeLists.txt` file to `find_package(TBB REQUIRED)` and link the corresponding targets when required (depending on the standard library, version, etc.). It looks like Conan is already offering a package that hides all that stuff from the user. You just get [parallelstl](https://bintray.com/conan-community/conan/parallelstl%3Aconan) and that's it. Will we have something similar in CMake in the future?

We can already use these parallel algorithms in CMake today, but it would be great to make it easier to create such projects.

Comment: Um, which implementations of the standard library are doing this? The standard library is supposed to be self-contained. If yours requires you to link to some other library, then it's a poor quality implementation.

Comment: @PeteBecker GCC 9's `libstdc++` (v9.1+)

Comment: https://youtu.be/-KT8gaojHUU describes the current situation. Apparently, `libcxx` should also depend on TBB as it uses the same implementation given by Intel. However, their plan is to replace the parallel backend at some point in the future.

Comment: Regarding CMake in TBB: recently TBB migrated to CMake, currently it is not released to production yet, but available on [master](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/tree/master) and [onetbb_2021](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/tree/onetbb_2021) branches.

Moreover [TBB releases](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/releases) support CMake integration. [Here](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/blob/tbb_2020/cmake/README.rst#binary-package-integration) are some instructions for TBB 2020 and older how to use it with `find_package(TBB)`.

Comment: @Touloudou, mmm, sounds like one of these replacements that we wait forever but never happen.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 21.10 with GCC and TBB (`libtbb-dev 2020.3-1`) installed.
Since TBB uses `pkg-config` what worked for me is this:

```
# file CMakeLists.txt

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(TBB REQUIRED tbb)
link_libraries(PkgConfig::TBB)
```

Unfortunately, when I later installed `intel-oneapi 2021.4.0` which includes its own TBB (in `/opt/intel/oneapi`) this stopped working.
This newer version of TBB cannot be used as a backed for GCC's (parallel) STL apparently (generates compilation errors in my system), so I did this in order to pick the system's TBB and not the `/opt/intel` version.

```
link_libraries(-ltbb) #(PkgConfig::TBB)
```

This defeats the purpose of CMake, so I am also looking for a more robust solution.
My recommendation at the moment is do not install `oneapi`'s TBB if what you want is to make it work with system's GCC.