# c++17 parallel algorithms and CMake on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17

I had installed gcc-11/g++-11 and tbb

```
$ dpkg -l | grep tbb                                                                                                                                                  
ii  libtbb-dev:amd64                     2020.1-2                              amd64        parallelism library for C++ - development files
ii  libtbb2:amd64                        2020.1-2                              amd64        parallelism library for C++ - runtime files
$ dpkg -l | grep gcc-11
ii  gcc-11                               11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04                 amd64        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-11-base:amd64                    11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04                 amd64        GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libgcc-11-dev:amd64                  11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04                 amd64        GCC support library (development files)
$ dpkg -l | grep g++-11
ii  g++-11                               11.1.0-1ubuntu1~20.04                 amd64        GNU C++ compiler
```

then, I wrote cmake like below

https://github.com/yumetodo/SigContrastFastAviUtl/blob/master/test/CMakeLists.txt

```
...
find_package(TBB REQUIRED tbb)
...
target_link_libraries(SigContrastFastAviUtl_test ${TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS})
...
```

However, it's seemed me that find_package doesn't work and link error was occurred.

```
$ cmake -B build -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-11 -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-11
-- Configuring done
You have changed variables that require your cache to be deleted.
Configure will be re-run and you may have to reset some variables.
The following variables have changed:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= g++-11
CMAKE_C_COMPILER= gcc-11
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER= g++-11

-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++-11
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++-11 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h
-- Looking for C++ include pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-11
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-11 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/yumetodo/SigContrastFastAviUtl/test/build

$ cmake --build build/                                                                                                                                                 
Scanning dependencies of target SigContrastFastAviUtl_test
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SigContrastFastAviUtl_test.dir/LUT.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SigContrastFastAviUtl_test.dir/random.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SigContrastFastAviUtl_test.dir/RSigmoidTable.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SigContrastFastAviUtl_test.dir/SigmoidTable.cpp.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/SigContrastFastAviUtl_test.dir/test.cpp.o
/home/yumetodo/SigContrastFastAviUtl/test/test.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void iu_Analyzer_x_iutest_x_calcAverage_Test::Body()’:
/home/yumetodo/SigContrastFastAviUtl/test/test.cpp:114:19: warning: unused variable ‘_’ [-Wunused-variable]
  114 |         for (auto _ : std::views::iota(0, 1000)) input.emplace_back(d(engine));
      |                   ^
/home/yumetodo/SigContrastFastAviUtl/test/test.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void iu_Analyzer_x_iutest_x_calcStdev_Test::Body()’:
/home/yumetodo/SigContrastFastAviUtl/test/test.cpp:124:19: warning: unused variable ‘_’ [-Wunused-variable]
  124 |         for (auto _ : std::views::iota(0, 1000)) input.emplace_back(d(engine));
      |                   ^
[100%] Linking CXX executable SigContrastFastAviUtl_test
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/SigContrastFastAviUtl_test.dir/test.cpp.o: in function `tbb::task_group_context::task_group_context(tbb::internal::string_index)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb18task_group_contextC2ENS_8internal12string_indexE[_ZN3tbb18task_group_contextC5ENS_8internal12string_indexE]+0x41): undefined reference to `tbb::task_group_context::init()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/SigContrastFastAviUtl_test.dir/test.cpp.o: in function `tbb::task::task()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb4taskC2Ev[_ZN3tbb4taskC5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for tbb::task'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/SigContrastFastAviUtl_test.dir/test.cpp.o: in function `tbb::task::~task()':
.
.
.
```

([full log is here](https://pastebin.com/i0N5rndt))

I watched below but not resolved.

- [c++17 parallel algorithms and CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64943235/c17-parallel-algorithms-and-cmake)
- https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/blob/tbb_2020/cmake/README.rst#binary-package-integration

How should I do?

---

```
diff --git a/test/CMakeLists.txt b/test/CMakeLists.txt
index 46dcc93..8b662dc 100644
--- a/test/CMakeLists.txt
+++ b/test/CMakeLists.txt
@@ -60,6 +60,7 @@ if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC OR CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUC)
   if(WIN32)
     target_link_libraries(SigContrastFastAviUtl_test wsock32 ws2_32)
   endif()
-  target_link_libraries(SigContrastFastAviUtl_test ${TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS})
+  #target_link_libraries(SigContrastFastAviUtl_test ${TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS})
+  target_link_libraries(SigContrastFastAviUtl_test TBB::tbb)
 endif()
 target_link_libraries(SigContrastFastAviUtl_test Threads::Threads)
```

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:58 (add_executable):
  Target "SigContrastFastAviUtl_test" links to target "TBB::tbb" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?


-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
make: *** [Makefile:296: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

Comment: `${TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS})` is this normal? Why not `target_link_libraries(SigContrastFastAviUtl_test tbb)`? Why the `_IMPORTED_TARGETS`?

Comment: @KamilCuk: Variable `TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS` is described in the [documentation](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/blob/tbb_2020/cmake/README.rst#tbbconfig). According to that documentation, imported targets themselves are named like ``TBB:tbb``.

Comment: TBB::tbb is also not worked for me.

Comment: You use `find_package(TBB)` but configuration output contains **none message** about executing it. Compare e.g. with `find_package(Threads)` and "Found Threads: TRUE" in the output. As far as I know, if `find_package(XXX)` uses [config mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#full-signature-and-config-mode), then it should output the message in any case. Try to use `find_package(TBB CONFIG REQUIRED tbb)` for force that config mode.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sZf48q8J config mode didn't show useful information for me.